# A 4 way SQL query including a count

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 4 tables:

> 1. ad (id, ...)
> 2. website (id, title, URL, ...)
> 3. space (id, website_id, ...)
> 4. ad_space_counter (id, ad_id, website_id, space_id, impression_counter, click_counter)

A website may have 2 or 3 spaces assigned to it.

Now what I wish to achieve is to make one SELECT and get the following:

> 1. ad_id
> 2. website_id
> 3. URL (from website table)
> 4. title (from website table)
> 5. impression_counter (but the TOTAL of all spaces assigned to that specific website_id)
> 6. click_counter (but the TOTAL of all spaces assigned to that specific website_id)

So if we have ad_id =1 and website_id = 1 but have 3 spaces with website_id = 1 then ad_space_counter will generate 3 entries each with their own specific impression and click counter. This SELECT must get the total of all of these and show it in one result.

Thanks.

Comment: Use "group by" clause.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Show us what you have written so far and what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use following, please note column "ad_id" not included in column list. So query below can be consider as stats by website.

```
select 
       a.website_id,
       website.url,
       website.title,
       sum(a.impression_counter) as impression_counter,
       sum(a.click_counter) as click_counter
from ad_space_counter a, 
     ad,
     website
     space
where ad.id = a.ad_id
   and website.id = a.website_id
   and space.id = a.space_id
group by 
       a.website_id,
       website.url,
       website.title
```